# How do I pass parameters with router.push in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, parameters, refresh, router

I'm working on a vue.js application. I'm trying to pass parameters in a redirect from one component to another like this:

```
      this.$router.push({
        path: '/my-path',
        query: {
          anArray: [...]
        }
      });
```

Once the component at my-path loads, I'm able to retrieve the parameters like this:

```
const theArray = this.$route.query.anArray;
```

The problem is that as soon as I refresh the page, the parameters are gone. When I open Chrome DevTools and put a break point where I retrieve the array from $route.query, I see this:

```
0: "[object Object]"
1: "[object Object]"
2: "[object Object]"
```

It seems obvious that it's getting this from the url which is:

```
http://localhost:8080/my-path?anArray=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&anArray=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&anArray=%5Bobject%20Object%5D
```

It doesn't seem to realize the 'object' terms in the url are just encodings of actual objects, which are available from $route.query the first time it loads.

Is there another way to pass parameters to a component using $router.push() such that the parameters persist on the page even after refreshing?

I could just try:

```
this.$router.push('/my-path?anArray=[...]');
```

...but my goal is to hide the parameters from the user (so don't show them in the url). This is another reason I'm looking for an alternate way of passing parameters (it doesn't even hide them).

I also tried:

```
      this.$router.push({
        path: '/my-path',
        params: {
          anArray: [...]
        }
      });
```

...but this made the parameters unavailable in the component (I wonder if this has anything to do with our global router which routes '/my-path' to the MyPath component without specifying parameters; is it wiping out the parameters?).

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use localStorage to store the query parameters?... and after the refresh retrive them

Comment: The `params` are only valid for named routes, not paths. If you init your `/my-path` route with a name, you could pass `params`.

Comment: What does it mean to init my /my-path?

Comment: I mean configuring  your routes. The route config for `/my-path` should have a `name` prop, which you'd use when pushing the route. See https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html

Comment: Ah, so I tried that and it works. I can now access this.$route.prams. However, it doesn't solve the larger problem. I still lose the parameters when I refresh the page. Would you suggest nachodd's solution of using localStorage?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to hide the parameters from the user, you must not use query. Instead, you should use parameters. Here I let you an example:

```js
//routes.js
path: '/:data',
name: 'Home',
component: () => import('pages/YourPage.vue')

//Passing parameters
this.$router.push({
      name: 'Home',
      params: { data: yourData}
    });

//Receiving parameters in Home component
created() {
    console.log('Params: ', this.$route.params);
}
```

I hope this could be usefull

Comment: This answer put me on the right track, but it is missing valuable info: `Note: params are ignored if a path is provided`, hope this helps people stumbling upon this answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andy. Your 4 year old answer still helped me just now.

Answer (score -1):

While `params` suggested @elC0mpa is a correct answer here are some alternatives depending on the use case:

**`localStorage`/`SessionStorage`**

Save the paramters into `localStorage`/`SessionStorage` and retrieve them in the loading sequence of your destination-page as @nachodd pointed out.

⚠ It should be noted that only key value pairs in form of strings are being saved into these storages.
You will need something along the line of

```
localStorage.setItem(itemKey,JSON.stringify(itemValue))
```

to set the values and

```
const itemValue = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(itemKey))
```

to recive it. Also  `localStorage.removeItem(itemKey)` for cleanup.

---

**`vuex store`**

You may want to consider saving your data in the store all together and access it from any vue-component.
The commands needed are `this.$store.commit('pathToStore/setterForKey',value)` to save something into the store and `this.$store.getters[pathToStore/getterForKey']` to receive the items value.

⚠ It should be noted that you need to set up the store accordingly with every state setter/mutation, getter and action. See [this documentation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#getting-vuex-state-into-vue-components).